# Blender Refraction BSDF not working

Tags: shaders

I am trying to use a Refraction Shader for one of my projects.

However, the object I am attempting to use a Refraction BSDF with is showing up as it would with no material applied.

Steps to recreate:

1. Create a torus with double the standard size
2. Create a cube
3. Subdivide the cube 10 times and use "To Sphere" to make the cube a sphere
4. Give the cube (Now a sphere) a refraction shader

Picture:
[image: Sphere with a refraction shader]

(While the picture is in Eevee, the project file I'm using is in Cycles (GPU Compute and Experimental) but it looks identical to the picture)

Does anyone know how to fix this? ( I am in Blender 3.4 )

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Answer (score 1):

Refraction works out of the box in Cycles. In Eevee,

For Eevee, you need to enable it in the Render settings and in the material's settings:

[image]

But with your scene, you need to be at a certain angle to see anything other than the solid grey of the environment:

[image: demo gif]

Comment: I tried using your method, but the sphere is still grey. I think this might be because of a geometry node setup I'm using. I'll link the video I'm following.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWv1Ajc3tfU&t=772s

Comment: please upload your file as per the screenshots on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and then [edit] your question to add the download link.